# Selecting a card is selecting other cards in horizontal list

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am using [simple coverflow](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/simple_coverflow) plugin for an app. Each container is scrollable horizontally and has a title with 3 choices as `Card`.

[image]

Issue is when I select any of the card choice, it selects same option on other cards in the list as well, as shown below:

[image]

As you can see above, the leftmost and rightmost cards shows the selected card option in green color when I select card # 1 from first container.

What do I need to do so that I should be able to select an option from center card which doesn't highlight / select same option on other cards ?

Code below:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
            body: new CoverFlow(
              dismissedCallback: disposeDismissed,
              currentItemChangedCallback: (int index) {
                print(index);
              },
              height: 600,
              itemCount: d.length,
              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return Container(
                  child: Card(
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30)),
                    child: Column(children: <Widget>[
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 25.0),
                        child: Text(
                          "Test",
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 20.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        ),),
                      Container(
                          height: 50.0,
                          child: GestureDetector(
                            child: Card(
                                color: _c
                                    ? Colors.lightGreen
                                    : Colors.white,
                                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0)),
                                margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                    horizontal: 10, vertical: 6),
                                child: Center(
                                    child: Text("1",
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            fontSize: 18.0),
                                        textAlign: TextAlign.center))
                            ),
                            onTap: () {
                              setState(() {
                                _s = true;
                                _c = true;
                                _w = false;
                                _wr = false;
                              });
                            },)),
                      Container(
                          height: 50.0,
                          child: GestureDetector(
                            child: Card(
                                color:
                                    _w ? Colors.redAccent : Colors.white,
                                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0)),
                                margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                    horizontal: 10, vertical: 6),
                                child: Center(
                                    child: Text(
                                  "2",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 18.0),
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                ))),
                            onTap: () {
                              setState(() {
                                _s = false;
                                _c = false;
                                _w = true;
                                _wr = false;
                              });
                            },
                          )),
                      Container(
                          height: 50.0,
                          child: GestureDetector(
                            child: Card(
                                color: _wr
                                    ? Colors.redAccent
                                    : Colors.white,
                                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0)),
                                margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                    horizontal: 10, vertical: 6),
                                child: Center(
                                  child: Text(
                                    "3",
                                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: 18.0),
                                  ),)),
                            onTap: () {
                              setState(() {
                                _s = false;
                                _c = false;
                                _w = false;
                                _wr = true;
                              });
                            },
                          )),
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 25.0),
                      )
                    ]
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ));}

  Widget widgetBuilder(int i) {
    if (d.length == 0) {
      return Container();
    } else {
      print([i % d.length]);
      return d[i % d.length];
    }}
  disposeDismissed(int dismissedItem, DismissDirection direction) {
    d.removeAt(dismissedItem % d.length);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to specify the index and the currentIndex, this code works:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:simple_coverflow/simple_coverflow.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
      home: MyApp(),
    ));

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  int curerntIndex = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
        body: new CoverFlow(
      dismissedCallback: disposeDismissed,
      currentItemChangedCallback: (int index) {
        print(index);
        setState(() {
          curerntIndex = index;
        });
      },
      height: 600,
      itemCount: d.length,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return Item(index, curerntIndex);
      },
    ));
  }
}

class Item extends StatefulWidget {
  final int index;
  final int curerntIndex;
  Item(this.index, this.curerntIndex);

  @override
  _ItemState createState() => _ItemState(index, curerntIndex);
}

class _ItemState extends State<Item> {
  final int index;
  final int curerntIndex;

  bool _s = true;
  bool _c = true;
  bool _w = false;
  bool _wr = false;

  _ItemState(this.index, this.curerntIndex);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Card(
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30)),
        child: Column(children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 25.0),
            child: Text(
              "Test",
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
              height: 50.0,
              child: GestureDetector(
                child: Card(
                    color: _c ? Colors.lightGreen : Colors.white,
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0)),
                    margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 6),
                    child: Center(
                        child: Text("1",
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),
                            textAlign: TextAlign.center))),
                onTap: () {
                  if (index == curerntIndex) {
                    setState(() {
                      _s = true;
                      _c = true;
                      _w = false;
                      _wr = false;
                    });
                  }
                },
              )),
          Container(
              height: 50.0,
              child: GestureDetector(
                child: Card(
                    color: _w ? Colors.redAccent : Colors.white,
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0)),
                    margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 6),
                    child: Center(
                        child: Text(
                      "2",
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    ))),
                onTap: () {
                  if (index == curerntIndex) {
                    setState(() {
                      _s = false;
                      _c = false;
                      _w = true;
                      _wr = false;
                    });
                  }
                },
              )),
          Container(
              height: 50.0,
              child: GestureDetector(
                child: Card(
                    color: _wr ? Colors.redAccent : Colors.white,
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0)),
                    margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 6),
                    child: Center(
                      child: Text(
                        "3",
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),
                      ),
                    )),
                onTap: () {
                  if (index == curerntIndex) {
                    setState(() {
                      _s = false;
                      _c = false;
                      _w = false;
                      _wr = true;
                    });
                  }
                },
              )),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 25.0),
          )
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: One issue though with this approach is, the selection resets if I move away from container while moving left or right. I want to keep the selection intact. Any idea how can persist the selection ?

Comment: So, in this case, you are starting to get a big state, setState is not enough which means you need to use a state management library: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options

Answer (score 2):

I think that you use the same state for your 3 cards, so the `_c` var is the same for all your 3 cards.

You can create a new `StatefulWidget` that build a card (and have it's own `_c` var inside of it) or you can use an array (`List` or `Map`) indexed by the `index` from `CoverFlow` in your actual widget.

**Option 1:**

```dart
class CustomCard extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CustomCardState createState() => _CustomCardState();
}

class _CustomCardState extends State<CustomCard> {
  // Initialise here or in `initState()` method.
  bool _s = false;
  bool _c = false;
  bool _w = false;
  bool _wr = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30)),
        child: Column(children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 25.0),
            child: Text(
              "Test",
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
              height: 50.0,
              child: GestureDetector(
                child: Card(
                    color: _c ? Colors.lightGreen : Colors.white,
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0)),
                    margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 6),
                    child: Center(
                        child: Text("1",
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),
                            textAlign: TextAlign.center))),
                onTap: () {
                  setState(() {
                    _s = true;
                    _c = true;
                    _w = false;
                    _wr = false;
                  });
                },
              )),
          Container(
              height: 50.0,
              child: GestureDetector(
                child: Card(
                    color: _w ? Colors.redAccent : Colors.white,
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0)),
                    margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 6),
                    child: Center(
                        child: Text(
                      "2",
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                    ))),
                onTap: () {
                  setState(() {
                    _s = false;
                    _c = false;
                    _w = true;
                    _wr = false;
                  });
                },
              )),
          Container(
              height: 50.0,
              child: GestureDetector(
                child: Card(
                    color: _wr ? Colors.redAccent : Colors.white,
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0)),
                    margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 6),
                    child: Center(
                      child: Text(
                        "3",
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0),
                      ),
                    )),
                onTap: () {
                  setState(() {
                    _s = false;
                    _c = false;
                    _w = false;
                    _wr = true;
                  });
                },
              )),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 25.0),
          )
        ]));
  }
}
```

```dart
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      body: new CoverFlow(
        dismissedCallback: disposeDismissed,
        currentItemChangedCallback: (int index) {
          print(index);
        },
        height: 600,
        itemCount: d.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return Container(
            child: CustomCard()
          );
        },
      ));}

  Widget widgetBuilder(int i) {
    if (d.length == 0) {
      return Container();
    } else {
      print([i % d.length]);
      return d[i % d.length];
    }}
  disposeDismissed(int dismissedItem, DismissDirection direction) {
    d.removeAt(dismissedItem % d.length);
  }
```

You can add options in your `CustomCard` widget.

**Option 2:**

Create a class for your data :

```dart
class MyData {
  bool s = false;
  bool c = false;
  bool w = false;
  bool wr = false;
}
```

Create a list to store your data (in your State):

```dart
  List<MyData> _cardsData;

  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    _cardsData = List.generate(d.length, (index) => MyData());
  }
```

Use the list:

```dart
// ...
onTap: () {
  setState(() {
    _cardsData[index].c = true;
  })
}
// ...
```

Comment: This sounds promising. Can you show me code sample of both options you suggested ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It has been helpful.

Answer (score 0):

no its not you are the one who changes the color using _c to color green so it changes in all of them but actually you are choosing only one.as in flutter you don't have to type new to create new gesture detector so if you want to change the color only for the tapped cell do it by the index you get from currentItemChangedCallback: (int index), or by changing the tapped widget color only.

Comment: Can you show how can I make use of `currentItemChangedCallback` to tap on cell ?

Comment: again you are clicking only on one and the event fires only for one.

Comment: so the tap actually works it is just the color tell me how is your business to give you the best answer on how to change the color for each card hope you understand what i am saying

Comment: I don't want to change color. I am doing that if I select #2, # 3. I want to highlight only the selected cell and that should not highlight cells from other container.

Comment: ok here what you should do, currentItemChangedCallback send you the index of the current coverflow right? just create an array for each row in the list like here you have 3 coveflow create an array with 3 length and add the bool values in it and according to index you get from currentItemChangedCallback ,change the value in the array like arrayOfColors[index]=green; ps : you can put boolean values in the array if you want

Comment: or you can use map instead of the array whatever suits you.

Comment: Ok. It would be good if you could show me code sample of what you are suggesting, using the code I shared originally.